# How to add UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark in the middle of the cell in iphone?

Tags: iphone, properties, cell

In my iPhone application I have used (`UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`) to add the checkmarks in the cells, - it is added to the cell at the right side of the cell.

I want the checkmarks to display in the middle of the cell and after that a string should display. So that the user can set the cell item as checked or unchecked.

Please provide any solution or any code for adding the (`UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`) in the middle of the cell.

Comment: Subclass; custom view; different design.

I'd pick the third one.

Comment: @JoePasq you should make this an answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to do this.  You will have to create a cell, then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you will need to either add a custom subview, or return a custom cell and tell it to display the custom checkmark you added based on the data state.

Answer (score 1):

The accessory view of the cell is always on the right side, outside of the cell's content view (see the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW10) for more on this). If you want to do something like this, you really need to create your own cell class, and draw the checks yourself.

Speaking as a user, this design seems sort of confusing, and definitely not what I'd expect. What's the string you're displaying to the right of the check? Maybe something like the  [`UITableViewCellStyleValue1`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewCellStyleValue1) style cell would work, instead? (See [Standard Styles for Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW14) for more.)

Comment: Agreed that it's not something you'd normally want to do but I found one case where I needed to do it: I wanted to have both a checkmark and an alphabetical index on the right of the screen. I ended up using a custom view to put the check mark on the left.